# Clearing a page and reloading a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a small angular app that takes in a search query, sends it to an elasticsearch node I've got set up, and then displays the result set on screen.

My problem is that when I make a new query, the results gets appended to the end of the current result set. What I would like it to do is to erase whatever is currently on the page, and reload it with only the new data, much like how searching for something on Google returns a completely new set of results.

Is there any way to do this? Code below for reference.

```
// this is the controller that displays the reuslts.
var displayController = function($scope, $rootScope, $window, notifyingService) {
    var dataReady = function(event, data) {
        $scope.resultSet = notifyingService.getData();
    }
    $rootScope.$on('data-ready', dataReady)
}

app.controller("displayController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$window", "notifyingService", displayController]);

// this is the service that's responsible for setting the data
var notifyingService = function($http, $rootScope) {
    var svc = {
        _data: [],
        setData: setData,
        getData: getData
    };

    function getData() {
        return svc._data;
    }

    function setData(data) {
        var base_obj = data.hits.hits
        console.log("Setting data to passed in data.");
        console.log('length of dataset: ' + base_obj.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < base_obj.length; i++){
            svc._data.push(base_obj[i]._source);
        }
        $rootScope.$broadcast('data-ready', svc._data);
}   
return svc;

};

app.factory("notifyingService", ["$http", "$rootScope", notifyingService]);
```

Comment: Have you tried re-initializing to an empty object in `getData()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In setData just before the loop re-initialize svc._data

```
svc._data = [];
```

Comment: Wow it was that simple. And here I was digging through the $route and ui-router docs for any kind of reload() function.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Clear you svc._data before you start adding the new query.

```
function setData(data) {
   var base_obj = data.hits.hits;

   svc._data = [];//reset your array before you populate it again.

   for(var i = 0; i < base_obj.length; i++){
      svc._data.push(base_obj[i]._source);
   }

   $rootScope.$broadcast('data-ready', svc._data);
}
```